# 403 error: Required SSL in response error when trying to get data from server

Tags: .net, ssl, iis

I'm working with .NET and have a backend and I'm trying to get data from a different frontend project both URL are http. But I'm getting 403 forbidden: SSL Required error.
I looked in applicationhost.config and sslflag is set to false.
What am I missing?

Comment: What about your application bindings in IIS? Are you bound to https or http

Comment: What exactly is recorded in IIS log files? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/http-status-code

Answer (score 0):

If you have not assigned a certificate to your website, you can check whether you have set "required SSL" for the website.

1. Open IIS Manager.
2. Click on your website.
3. Click on the "SSL Settings" in the IIS section.
4. Uncheck "Require SSL".